# Installing Django "open file with" message when using the "setup.py install" command

Tags: django

I installed the latest version of Django from here: https://www.djangoproject.com/, unzipped the file and moved it to my desktop. Took note of the file path, opened the command prompt and changed the directory to that file path and then typed 'setup.py install' it first said 'open with' and I picked to open with python.exe (the python command line) and now it says 'error: no commands supplied'.. If I try 'python setup.py install' it says "python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". Any idea why?

Comment: Add path of python.exe to your environment path.

Comment: Environment path meaning? Environmental Variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the python.exe file to your system PATH.

Heres a quick link on how to set/update your path on windows http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Once you have that python.exe file added to your path you can run python from the command line.

Comment: Okay, python.exe is installed in C:\Users\me\Desktop\July\programs\Python27, so when I go to system variables and click 'edit' on path, a couple paths already exist (C:\path1;C:\path2; etc.).. should I add C:\Users\me\Desktop\July\programs\Python27\python.exe
as a path?

Comment: yea add it to the end of the list of paths
with a semicolon before, so like this:
;C:\Users\me\Desktop\July\programs\Python27\python.exe

Comment: Perfect, this worked.. I added ;C:\Users\me\Desktop\July\programs\Python27\python.exe
as a path and then opened cmd, changed the directory to the djano- one and then did "python setup.py install".. thanks!